# What is a good approach to return user information (like roles) after logging in?

Tags: angular, spring-security-oauth2

For a project I've made a spring boot authorization server and a resource server. I've implemented the oauth2 password flow. I'm also creating an angular web application that's going to use the data of the endpoints of the resource server. The resource server checks the token by using the authorization server.

I would like to know the best approach to communicate user info after logging in. I need information like roles/user id to show a different page, hide certain functions or collect user specific data from the resource server by using the received token.

I've made a CustomTokenEnhancer which can add additional info to my token response.

```java
@Override
    public OAuth2AccessToken enhance(OAuth2AccessToken accessToken, OAuth2Authentication authentication) {
        final Map<String, Object> additionalInfo = new HashMap<>();
        User user = (User) authentication.getPrincipal();
        additionalInfo.put("id", user.getId());
        additionalInfo.put("username", authentication.getName());
        additionalInfo.put("organization", user.getOrganization());
        additionalInfo.put("roles", user.getRoles());
        ((DefaultOAuth2AccessToken) accessToken).setAdditionalInformation(additionalInfo);
        return accessToken;
    }
```

This is an example of the response after asking for a token.

```
{
    "access_token": "233fda99-3ff7-4766-bfa3-3b211280c64f",
    "token_type": "bearer",
    "refresh_token": "286e7324-9b8a-46de-a0c7-45e21be552d4",
    "expires_in": 35999,
    "scope": "read write",
    "organization": "organization",
    "roles": [
        {
            "id": "1",
            "createdAt": null,
            "name": "ROLE_admin",
            "permissions": [
                {
                    "id": "1",
                    "createdAt": null,
                    "name": "create_profile"
                },
                {
                    "id": "2",
                    "createdAt": null,
                    "name": "read_profile"
                },
                {
                    "id": "3",
                    "createdAt": null,
                    "name": "update_profile"
                },
                {
                    "id": "4",
                    "createdAt": null,
                    "name": "delete_profile"
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "id": 1,
    "username": "test"
}
```

Is it safe to store information like the role in localstorage and use that for deciding which elements to hide/show of my webapp?

Answer (score 0):

That mainly depends what you mean by "elements".

From the moment your info is in the frontend your user has access to it, so he can modify it (whether you store it in the localstorage or anywhere else doesn't matter).

Knowing that, you can guess that it's the backend that has to make the decision of what your user has access to.

So if your frontend reads your localstorage to know if an "edit" button should be shown for exemple there is no problem as long as if the user make the button appear anyway your backend verifies he has the right to edit the thing, but if you want to hide sensitive info based on this criteria it's not a good idea, your backend should never had sent this info to begin with.

Comment: Well my backend endpoints are checking for stuff like roles and scopes.

What would be a better solution to communicate the user role and protect particular endpoints with an role based auth guard for example?

Comment: As long as your "backend endpoints are checking for stuff" I'd say you are good, you can't do much more on front-end, your user, if they want to see what an admin view looks like, can always do a sort of man-in-the-middle "attack" to make their front believe they are admin.

Answer (score 0):

You have to decide authorization on your backend. To protect the frontend logic you could use tools like Jscrambler which you can implment in angular-cli and the build process. Jscrambler makes it very hard to debug code.